# Styles won't change Title text and Button highlight animator colour in Cast Introductory Overlay

Tags: android, chromecast

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/customize_ui), Cast Introductory overlay is customizable via Styles.

```
<item name="castIntroOverlayStyle">@style/CustomCastIntroOverlay</item>
<style name="CustomCastIntroOverlay" parent="CastIntroOverlay">
    <item name="castButtonTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.CustomCastIntroOverlay.Button</item>
    <item name="castTitleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.CustomCastIntroOverlay.Title</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.CustomCastIntroOverlay.Button" parent="android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.CustomCastIntroOverlay.Title"parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

However, no matter what colour you put in the styles, the TitleText and Cast Button overlay colour (the one surrounding the button) does not change.

This is reproducible in the [sample code](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) also.

I have [reported the bug in the repo](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/issues/102)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue with a hack:

```
                val overlay = IntroductoryOverlay.Builder(this@CastActivity, it)
                    .setTitleText(configHolder.tr("cast.message.overlay"))
                    .setOverlayColor(R.color.imageOverlayBackground)
                    .setSingleTime()
                    .build()

                overlay.show()

                // A hack to change colors. Note that the color of button itself is changed in the Styles
                (overlay as? ViewGroup)?.apply {
                    // Title text color
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cast_featurehighlight_help_text_header_view)?.setTextColor(configHolder.getColor(R.color.imageOverlayParagraphForeground, 0.9F))
                    // The highlight color surrounding the button
                    findViewById<View>(R.id.cast_featurehighlight_view).apply {
                        try {
                            val classFields = this::class.java.declaredFields
                            for (classField in classFields) {
                                // Getting class member that is InnerZoneDrawable
                                if (classField.type.toString().contains("InnerZoneDrawable", true)) {
                                    classField.isAccessible = true
                                    // Get an object of this class member, convert it to Drawable, and apply color filter
                                    val innerZoneDrawable = classField.get(this)
                                    (innerZoneDrawable as Drawable).apply {
                                        colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(configHolder.getColor(R.color.buttonPrimaryDefaultBackground), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                                    }

                                    // Now for the circle animator, we need to access Paint variables inside InnerZoneDrawable and apply color filter
                                    val innerZoneClassFields = innerZoneDrawable.javaClass.declaredFields

                                    for (innerZoneClassField in innerZoneClassFields) {
                                        if (innerZoneClassField.type == Paint::class.java) {
                                            innerZoneClassField.isAccessible = true
                                            (innerZoneClassField.get(innerZoneDrawable) as Paint).apply {
                                                colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(configHolder.getColor(R.color.buttonPrimaryDefaultBackground), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Timber.w(e)
                        }
                    }
                }
```